# MySQL PASSWORD () doesn't work with SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, passwords

The password function in mysql works fine with me in inserting and updating such as here:

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO `account`(`Gender`, `Birth_date`, `Name`, `UserName`, `Password`, `Email`, `Type`) VALUES ('" . $gender . "' , '" . $birthdate . "' , '" . $name . "' , '" . $username . "' , password('" . $password . "') , '" . $email . "' , 'Member' ) ";
```

it insert the hashed password correctly

but when i try to retrieve it in log in code it doesn't work !

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM account where UserName = '" . $username . "' AND password = password('" . $password . "') ");
```

I tried to use

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

but the result is same
I even tried to use it in PHPMyAdmin as a select query, and the same error !

### UPDATE

I used MD5()
and it worked with me !

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not an error message mysql spits out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password):

> #### Note
>
> The [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should *not* use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider [`MD5()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) or [`SHA2()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) instead. Also see [RFC 2195, section 2 (Challenge-Response Authentication Mechanism (CRAM))](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2195.html), for more information about handling passwords and authentication securely in your applications.

Also, if you're rolling your own authentication system (which I'd *strongly* discourage), you really should read both [The definitive guide to form based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477578) and [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401684).

Comment: @user3504563: One can only therefore conclude that you followed none of the advice I just gave (I strongly discouraged rolling your own auth system, the "Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords" link explicitly says "**Never hash passwords with SHA1 or MD5! Modern crackers can exceed 60 and 180 billion hashes/second (respectively).**" and "The definitive guide to form based website authentication" contains a whole host of other important information you've undoubtedly ignored).  Using MD5(), you may as well not bother hashing your passwords at all - just store them plaintext.

Comment: @user3504563 - Please please use the PHP function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead of the fast MD5. It is not possible to verify a password safely in an SQL statement, you first have to retrieve the password then you can use the function [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).